# How to fork your own repo on BitBucket?

Tags: fork, bitbucket

How to fork your own repo on BitBucket ?

I know how to [fork](https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucket/forking-a-repository-221449527.html) another user repo from web interface, and I know how to clone my repo.

But how to fork your own repo on BitBucket and ease a future pull request workflow?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Go to your repository, and then go to Actions -> Fork.

If you have the new navigation enabled, then go to your repository, click on the + on the left navigation bar and then Get to work -> Fork this repository.

Also, make sure that forking is enabled in repository settings (*for the existing repository*).

Comment: This is an import, exactly as cloning, This do not create a fork, because doesn't create a `master-fork` link in repo properties

Comment: @Y.N you can fork your own repo just like someone else's repo. Go to your repo and click Actions->Fork.

Comment: Oh yes. I see I disabled forking in repo settings. Swith it ON, and now forking is enble! Thank you!

Comment: Could @Gaby aka G. Petrioli update the answer with "check is forking is enabled in repo settings"

Answer (score 5):

First, create a new repository 'bar'.
Next, clone the existing project 'foo':

```
$ git clone git@bitbucket.org:YOURNAME/foo.git bar
```

Next, edit your Git config file and replace the origin URL with your new URL:

```
$ cd bar
$ vim .git/config
    [remote "origin"]
    fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
    url = git@bitbucket.org:YOURNAME/bar.git #replace foo with bar
```

Optionally add your original repo as an upstream source:

```
$ git remote add upstream git@bitbucket.org:YOURNAME/foo.git
```

Finally, push your new repository up to Bitbucket:

```
$ git push -u origin master
```

Now you can push/pull from your new repo (bar) as expected. You should also be able to merge upstream changes using the following command:

```
$ git fetch upstream
$ git merge upstream/master
```

credit: [bitdrift](http://bitdrift.com/post/4534738938/fork-your-own-project-on-github)

Answer (score 0):

On bitbucket server, it does not seem to be an option to fork from your own personal repository. I ran into this trying to move a personal repository to a public location. Possible options:

Get someone else to fork it for you or use a different login if available.

Or

From the project settings, "Move" the repository to the public location, then fork the moved repository back to the original location.